# Why request.Get.get() method is not working in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a Text Analyzer website using Django3.0.2 in a virtual env running on python3.7.4 . 
I want to fetch the data entered inside text box by the user to ge printed on my console. For some reason `request.Get.get()` method is not working and I'm seeing `AttributeError`.

**template** :

```
<body>
  <h3> Enter your text here </h3>
  <form action="/remvpc" method="get">
    <textarea name="text" id="" cols="30" rows="10" spellcheck="false"
     style="margin: 0px; width: 673px; height: 393px;">
    </textarea>
    <br>
    <button type="submit"> Anazlyze text </button>
  </form>
</body>
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def remove_pun(request):
dj_text = request.Get.get('text','default')
print(dj_text)
return HttpResponse("""remove punctuation <a href="/"> Back </a>""")`
```

**urls.py file of project**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='index'),
path('remvpc/', views.remove_pun, name='remove-pun'),
]
```

**ERROR**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/remvpc/?text=++++++++

Django Version: 3.0.2
Python Version: 3.7.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ankur/.local/share/virtualenvs/django_project_1-4W4x1zxU/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/ankur/.local/share/virtualenvs/django_project_1-4W4x1zxU/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/ankur/.local/share/virtualenvs/django_project_1-4W4x1zxU/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/ankur/DEV_1/django_project_1/src/django_project_1/views.py", line 17, in remove_pun
    dj_text = request.Get.get('text','default')

Exception Type: AttributeError at /remvpc/
Exception Value: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'Get'
```

Comment: it's `request.GET.get()` (as you could have found out by yourself just [reading the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#attributes))

Comment: I'm so sorry. How could I miss that? I'm totally lost. Thanks! How can I close this question with an answer?

Comment: Well, sometimes we can't see the forest for the trees I guess xD - I once lost 3 hours (and some hairs too) trying to find out why my (very simple) sql query crashed with a syntax error. Until I finally found out I was insisting on writing "UDPATE" instead of "UPDATE" :-/

Answer (score 6):

it is `request.GET.get(...)`, `Get` should be all caps.

[check it here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET)